# Capturing the key fob signal with SDR

Tags: software-defined-radio, rtl-sdr

Is it correct to assume that not all the key fob signals have preamble section? I am playing around with bunch of key fobs and I am trying my best to capture their OOK transmitted signals with RTL-SDR and Gnuradio companion.

I can not see any pattern for some of them. Does it mean that there is no preamble for some?

Comment: Everything I said about Garage door openers applies here too. **If** the key fob uses OOK, it's a very simplistic key fob, and it might or might not have a preamble. Unless you know e.g. from the FCC documentation that they use OOK, there's no reason to assume they do.

Comment: @Marcue Muller I have checked the FCC documentation. The frequencies are indicated but I can not find the modulation type. Do you know where I can get that? Thank you

Comment: Test repot is the answer I guess, I just found something.

Comment: This website describes the process in detail, with everything you need to know to do it yourself:  https://medium.com/@eoindcoolest/decoding-a-garage-door-opener-with-an-rtl-sdr-5a47292e2bda